# ¿Cómo puedo instalar la libreria Keyboard de python?

Tags: python

Al intentar instalar la libreria keyboard de python en el cmd me sale el siguiente error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:  
/packages/55/88/287159903c5b3fc6d47b651c7ab65a54dcf9c9916de546188a7f62870d6d/keyboard-0.13.5-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))).
```

Llevo unos cuantos dias intentando buscar una solucion y no encuentro nada que me sirva, he probado con "pip install keyboard", tambien con "py -m install keyboard", he intentado actualizar el pip con "py -m pip install --upgrade pip" e incluso poniendolo todo en el cmd abierto como administrador y me sale siempre el mismo error, porfavor necesito ayuda.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134986/discussion-on-question-by-tuespiner-como-puedo-instalar-la-libreria-keyboard-de).

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver el problema, lo que yo he tenido que hacer es cambiar la Dns por la de Google (8.8.8.8) y ya se me soluciono el problema.

Comment: Me alegro de que el cambio de DNS te haya resuelto el problema. Pero aún queda el interrogante de por qué inicialmente tenías un DNS que te resolvía a una IP "falsa" de un sitio que se quería hacer pasar por el repositorio Python. Esa parte es inquietante. Vigila de vez en cuando la configuración de tu DNS no vaya a cambiarse de nuevo "sola" (por la acción de un malware)